# adding html within var string?

Tags: javascript

Say I have

```
var b = 'I am a JavaScript hacker.'
```

How can I do this ?

```
var b = 'I am a <a href="foo.php">JavaScript hacker</a>.'
```

Is this dooable ?

I thought the question was clear. Apologies if it wasnt.

Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/ozzy/vWYQ2/

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Ok I have a text change script, that on hover changes text to another line of text .. and I wish to add a link within the result text I will create a fiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ozzy/vWYQ2/

Comment: What is criteria for selecting text from string which will become hyperlink text?

Comment: @422 What about this http://jsfiddle.net/vWYQ2/1/?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    var mem = $("#TA").html();
    $("#TA").hover(function() {
        $(this).stop().html( 'I am a <a href="foo.php">JavaScript hacker</a>.' );
    }, function() {
        $(this).stop().html( mem );
    });
});
```

I think you want something like this

[My code](http://jsfiddle.net/inspired_jw/zKRGW/9/)

**Edited: Due to the flickering issue.**

Comment: Thats great cept needs to have an id do i just go div.apple and change div id="apple" to initiate it ? because http://jsfiddle.net/ozzy/zKRGW/7/ is flawed ( not sure what I done wrong there )

Comment: @422 As you see I did not use an id. But you can use id and change it to $("#your_DOM_id") instead of $("div").

Comment: tried that and it flickers when you hover over it ? http://jsfiddle.net/ozzy/zKRGW/8/

Answer (score 2):

um... yes? that will give you a variable named b which holds `'I am a <a href="foo.php">JavaScript hacker</a>.'`

Answer (score 2):

Code from http://jsfiddle.net/vWYQ2/2/, this removes the hyperlink once mouse is out.

HTML

```
<div id="TA" onmousemove="changetext();" onmouseout="restore();">I am a JavaScript hacker.</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var originalBlock = document.getElementById("TA").innerHTML;
var timer;
function changetext()
{
    var id = document.getElementById("TA");
    if(originalBlock == null) originalBlock= id.innerHTML;
    var text = id.innerHTML;
    id.innerHTML = text.replace("JavaScript hacker", "<a href='foo.php'>JavaScript hacker</a>");
    if(timer != null)
    clearTimeout(timer);
}
function restore()
{
   timer = setTimeout(function()
             {
                 document.getElementById("TA").innerHTML = originalBlock;
             }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: But how about just one word , this is where I am getting stuck I dont want "<a href='foo.php'>JavaScript hacker</a>" I am after "JavaScript <a href='foo.php'>hacker</a>" .This is where I am getting stuck ( escaping the different sections correctly

Comment: @422 Try the new code it removes the hyper link. If you want to convert `hacker` to hyperlink in that case change the replace statement to `text.replace("hacker", "<a href='foo.php'>hacker</a>")`